# Linux chrome not launching in Jenkins

Tags: linux, google-chrome, jenkins, karma-jasmine

After chrome latest version auto update, Jenkins karma couldn't launch the chrome browser in linux slave machines.

It is working fine on October 17th 2017. i.e. running by 61.0.3163.100-1 version.

After the version update to 62.0.3202.62-1 chrome doesn't launch.

```
WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9877/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
Karma has exited with 1
```

**Reference:** https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable

Comment: HI , did you try to run your flow without Jenkins ?

did you change something in your flow ?